# Why Adobe Flash CS3 exports only class without symbol from other SWC

Tags: flash, flash-cs3, swc

I've created Common.swc using Flash CS3. It exports class `NotificationWindow`, symbol `CloseButton` and appropriate class. These symbol and class are used by `NotificationWindow`. Then I created Formula.swc which uses `NotificationWindow`. Formula.swc normally exports classes `NotificationWindow`, `CloseButton` but not `CloseButton` symbol.

Also I tried to create very simple Test.fla with Test.as:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import inobr.eft.common.ui.*;

    public class Test extends Sprite {
        public function Test() {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            NotificationWindow.show(stage, "Tets!", "Test test", true);
        }

    }
}
```

NotificationWindow displayed without CloseButton.

What I do wrong?